# Float and double precision in trigonometric functions

Tags: java, trigonometry

The IEEE 754 standard says that float (32 bit) use 23 bit for the mantissa, which permits to store all the digits of every reals up to roughly 10⁷. For trigonometric functions such as `cos()` or `sin()`, the least significant bits are important. Therefore one can expect the result of sin() and cos() of float variables to be wrong after 10⁷ as a part of mantissa is lost during encoding.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    System.out.println("for 10^" + i);
    System.out.println(Math.sin((float) Math.pow(10, i)));
    System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.pow(10, i)));
}
```

This code shows that `sin()` and `cos()` of float variables stays exact up to 10<sup>10</sup>, which is a behavior I don't understand... How can the `cos()` and `sin()` process the exact value as the parameter itself lacks precision?

Answer (score 1):

An IEEE float has 24 bits of precision in the mantissa (23 explicitly stored, plus 1 "hidden" bit). The key to the behavior you see is that when 10<sup>10</sup> is written in binary it is 34 bits long, but the last 10 bits are all "0". Therefore, the single precision representation is exact for this particular number.